# ffmpeg error that causes songs to be skipped in discord.py music bot

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

I'm making a music bot in python. Sometimes when the music is playing, such an error may come out

```
[tls @ 0x56540863c280] Error in the pull function.
[matroska,webm @ 0x565408639460] Read error
[tls @ 0x56540863c280] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
```

```
[https @ 0x55ef3042ae80] HTTP error 403 Forbidden
https://rr5---sn-qxoedne7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1643908737&ei=ILr7YYvvOfeA_tcP1P-O6AE&ip=34.70.213.61&id=o-AP2Y_3KL9ByYzaHpK9BTYU-rXEdyhVBdmAya4-RDcnhA&itag=249&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=up&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-qxoedne7%2Csn-5goeen7d&ms=au%2Conr&mv=u&mvi=5&pl=20&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=R7IIdhU6N1T67hOi5mk4h1gG&gir=yes&clen=1237668&dur=200.101&lmt=1643350535759614&mt=1643886547&fvip=4&keepalive=yes&fexp=24001373%2C24007246&c=WEB&txp=5432434&n=f5o7FLev4k11Jt4&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIhAI7fuWyVPY7zdiGm2FemrcqsDuQWjcqfSnLKxw66QoSwAiBOJHGVpoRCKu2ZnW3DPGxK8bKS-FfvyyxG2hRgg2TRVw%3D%3D&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgOWU5ecufOjhtuwQNdWX5l140N5cW7Hu01SfC9b6Zkg4CIQC0ZzrrXwUtf4qkvWZaQCEfWpOmZJhBmca0sYqqmxh75A==: Server returned 403 Forbidden (access denied)
```

```
[dash @ 0x5596ac7e6460] Could not read complete fragment.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5596acb12940] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[dash @ 0x5596ac7e6460] Could not read complete fragment.
```

A piece of code to launch a song:

```py
YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio/best','outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s','restrictfilenames': True,'noplaylist': True,'nocheckcertificate': True,'ignoreerrors': False,'logtostderr': False,'quiet': True,'no_warnings': True, 'forceipv4': True,'cookies': True, 'default_search': 'auto','encoding': 'utf-8', "simulate": True, 'audioformat': "mp3",'audioquality': 5,'source_address': '0.0.0.0',"bitrate": 320000,"prefer_ffmpeg": True,"usenetrc": True,"verbose": False}
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'options': '-vn'}
vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio( source = URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
vc.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(vc.source)
vc.source.volume = 1
```

How do I catch these errors or how do I fix them?

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg before options should be:

```
before_options='-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5'
```